# Blender 2.8 status bar

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I am writing with the help of Google translator.
 In the blender 2.8, the status bar went down (there is information about layers and vertices). How to raise the whole thing up? Is there any addon or customization?

Comment: select its top border and left click drag it down

Answer (score 1):

**Append to the top bar.**

The top bar in blender 2.8x is on the top, and the status bar is on the bottom.  The status bar can be toggled on and off with python.

```
bpy.context.screen.show_statusbar = False # off
```

AFAIK there is no way to move statusbar to top using python.  Would need to alter blender's source code.

[image]

As a workaround, the statistics previously in 2.79 displayed on info header (often at top of screen) are now in the status bar at bottom of screen.

Run the script below to append scene statistics to the top bar.

```
import bpy

def draw(self, context):
    scene = context.scene
    vl = context.view_layer
    self.layout.label(text=scene.statistics(vl))

def register():
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_HT_upper_bar.append(draw)

def unregister():
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_HT_upper_bar.remove(draw) 

if __name__ == "__main__":   
    register()
```

Alternatively could prepend the whole statusbar to the top bar, but this doesn't work as expected.

```
import bpy

bpy.types.TOPBAR_HT_upper_bar.prepend(bpy.types.STATUSBAR_HT_header.draw)
```

[image]
*Change the theme colors of the topbar header text*

To run automatically for all blend files, save the script, with a `.py` extension, eg `topbar_stats.py` in your *`2.80/scripts/startup`* folder, or for on a blend by blend basis: save in blend file, making sure once again the name has a `.py` extension,  and check the register checkbox.

[image]

Comment: ( I answer with the help of Google translator. )
 Wow This is really very cool!
 But this is a little wrong. How to move up the entire lower status bar (including information on keystrokes) above the tabs: location, simulation.

Comment: Edited to make it clearer that AFAIK the statusbar is hard-coded to the bottom of screen.  Would need to alter blender source to change.

Comment: (I use Google translator.) Thank you so much for the answer and for taking the time to go :)
@batFINGER

Comment: Cheers. (A good test of any translator is translating the result back to original.)