# Show the polycount of selected objects in object mode

Tags: interface, polycount

How to show the polycount statistics (faces, tris, etc) of selected objects in object mode? The bar on the bottom of screen shows polycount of the whole scene:

[image]

I know I can switch to edit mode and select the whole object to view its polycount, but there are two problems: 1) what if I want to know the combined polycount of two or more objects? 2) When there is a Decimate Modified applied, edit mode doesn't have the information of final result.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102597/finding-vertices-edges-faces-and-tris-using-python  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145452/blender-2-8-status-bar

Answer (score 6):

It's a workaround, but you can temporary hide every other object.

Select the desired object(s), press <kbd>Ctrl+i</kbd> to invert the selection, then <kbd>H</kbd> to hide : you can now read the statistics you want. Once done, <kbd>Alt+H</kbd> to un-hide.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a script to output the informations you need in the console :

```
import bpy

verts, edges, polys = 0, 0, 0
dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()  # Getting the dependency graph
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:

    obj = obj.evaluated_get(dg)
    # This gives the evaluated version of the object. Aka with all modifiers and deformations applied.  
    mesh = obj.to_mesh()  # Turn it into the mesh data block we want

    print(' Object :', obj.name)
    print('  Vertices :', len(mesh.vertices))
    print('  Edges    :', len(mesh.edges))
    print('  Polygons :', len(mesh.polygons))
    verts += len(mesh.vertices)
    edges += len(mesh.edges)
    polys += len(mesh.polygons)
print(f'Total : {verts} Verts, {edges} Edges, {polys} Polys')
```

I tried it with 3 objects and subdiv, decimate, build modifiers (not applied) :

[image]

The downside is you have to run the script each time you do it and check the console. With a bit of effort you can transform it into a custom operator and write the information somewhere in the 3D view.

Also I think it is not very efficient so it may slow down on heavy models.

[Source](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/146911/86891)

Answer (score 1):

> It's a workaround, but you can temporary hide every other object.
>
> Select the desired object(s), press Ctrl+i to invert the selection,
> then H to hide : you can now read the statistics you want. Once done,
> Alt+H to un-hide"

Actually there's a faster way ive just found out, is simply press Shift + H to hide every other objects